# Default font letter spacing

Tags: fonts, spacing

I have a slight issue while writing my thesis. The examination office of my university allows no more than 20 pages of text (and they are very strict about that).

They normally also require you to use "Times New Roman"; however, the LaTeX default font is okay, too.

I figured out that letter spacing of the default font compared to Times (\usepackage{mathptmx}) is much larger. Since I reached my page limit and still have something to say and don't really like the look of Times I was wondering whether there is another font similar to the default one but with smaller spacing?

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Comment: If you compile with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, you can use whatever font you want with the `fontspec` package, which will let you play with spacing directly. Otherwise, see [the font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html) and [the fonts available from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts) (which were likely included in your distribution).

Comment: However, first I'd try loading the `microtype` package. It can surprise you with how much space it can save. (`microtype` is short for microtypography -- tiny, tiny enhancements.)

Comment: Thanks Sean! The font catalogue I already knew about, but I wanted something very similar in style to the default one. As to the `microtype`
 package -- that's basically what I was looking for. I will try to play around a little and see whether I can cramp out a couple more rows :-)